# go template split string by the second to last character

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am trying to split a string only by the second to last character, for example:
Having this string xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
I would like to get only this xxx-xxx-xxx and remove the last part after the third "-" or the second last "-", the string will always have 4 "-" and character or numbers in between.

At the moment I have something like this
`{{ splitList "-" .Values.global.stackName | list ._0 ._1 ._2 | join "-" | quote }}`
Does not work because I dont know how to pipe the array from the first split int the second one and join them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `slice` function to get only the first 3 elements of the splitted list:

```
{{ slice (splitList "-" .Values.global.stackName) 0 3 | join "-" | quote }}
```

Also note that if your input is guaranteed to be of fixed format (that is, 3 characters then `-` then 3 chars again then `-` then 3 chars again before `-`), you may use `printf` with the proper format string to keep only the first (at most) 11 characters:

```
{{ printf "%.11s" .Values.global.stackName | quote }}
```

If the input only contains ASCII characters (no multi-byte unicode characters), you may also slice the input string to retain only the first 11 characters (bytes):

```
{{ slice .Values.global.stackName 0 11 | quote }}
```

Comment: I am using the slice:
{{ slice (splitList "-" .Values.global.stackName) 0 3 | join "-" | quote }}
It works good, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the piece you're missing is the [`initial`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#initial-mustinitial) template function, which takes a list as a parameter and returns new list without its last item.

```
{{ splitList "-" .Values.global.stackName | initial | join "-" | quote }}
```

(`splitList` and `join` aren't included in the Helm [Template Function List](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/) page.  But they come from a support library called [Sprig](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) which is mostly embedded into Helm as-is, and they're documented in its [String Slice Functions](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/string_slice.html) page.)

Comment: but this only removes the last part of the string I need to remove the two last parts of the string os like this: xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx -> xxx-xxx-xxx

Comment: You can call `initial` twice.  [`slice`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#slice-mustslice) is also an option, but doesn't fit into a pipeline quite as neatly.